# C# Solution structure & project naming

Tags: c#, namespaces, structure, project, default

My project consists of multiple servers, those servers use the same network library, and use alot of code in common (enumerations, collections etc...). The project has dependency on FluentNHibernate (might change to Entity Framework)

I would know in the first time how to structure my solution directory. Should I put my projects under a subdirectory, or in the same directory as the solution ?

And in the second time, I wonder about the naming conventions of project and the namespaces inside the projects.

Let's take an example, if I call my project Solution.ChatServer, the ChatServer class will be contained in this namespace, isn't the name a bit redundant ?

I plan to implement plugins soon, and I would like to make it the most easy possible and have everything well-designed.

I like the idea of having a project very modular, and I want to follow the maximum possible the .NET style

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the official guidelines for .Net when it comes to naming and design patterns: [naming assemblies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229048(v=vs.110).aspx), [framework design](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229042(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I already checked those and it doesn't help regarding the project structure. My product is my solution name, and I don't have company. I feel the Microsoft guidelines is more adapted for libraries than for programs

Comment: For the project structure itself I would suggest downloading and studying the code for nopCommerce. In my development team we used their framework and we continue to use that model of organizing our code/project/solutions.